# CocoaPod config to solve XCode 14, iOS16 Requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode14

In my project i have different targets, signed with different entities

in Xcode 14, some of the pods require signing, and however i could assign a signing team manually, it differs from target to target

**How to configure cocoapods to sign the dependency, with the targets signing?**

i found how to disable the signing for dependencies completely (putting the bellow into the Podfile), but this is not what i want (even it compiles), as i want to have it signed to fulfill Apples expectations

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
       end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the pods require signing?  I have had actual frameworks appearing in my pods projects when first moving to Xcode 14 which gives a "signing team required" error. The solution is to simply delete the framework (not the pod)

Comment: well but if you delete the framework, you delete the framework :) did you project work? may have been some old unused framwork

Comment: Not the source, but the product. It is hard to explain, but what I have been seeing is an actual built library in the pod projec; a .framework filet.  This is the thing that Xcode says needs to be signed. You can delete it. Nothing in your pods project requires signing.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 14, we were able to upload to AppStore without breaking any expectations by disabling code-signing... but only for some targets; so that might be particularly helpful.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

    if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end

  end
end
```